# Mysql query select 2 values with 1 Distinct

Tags: mysql

My table structure -

username : website

I want to select only unique **websites** 

I have tried running this query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT username,website from asd
```

But it selects the unique **combination**

example -

```
John    www.google.com 
Jack    www.google.com 
Tom     www.facebook.com
```

Query should return 
**John** - www.google.com 
   **Tom** - www.facebook.com

Thank you

Comment: Why not Jack and tom and on what basis are you saying John should come?

Comment: What is the logic by which John's record is retained over Jack's record?

Comment: John OR Jack should be ignored because google.com is not unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `GROUP BY` in your case:

```
SELECT username, website FROM asd GROUP BY website
```

Comment: Amazing solution, worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `DISTINCT` with more then one column, then it will search for distinct among the paired columns. So the data you are getting is absolutely right.

For your requirement, please elaborate why `John` is needed and not `Jack`?

Comment: John OR Jack should be taken , since google.com is a duplicate

Comment: And how you decide either it is John OR Jack ?

Comment: I guess it's up to mysql's  logic. This task of mine is not so important , so i can leave it for mysql to choose. But i would also like to know how to decide that